# Where to store data?

Tags: c++, windows, linux

I have created a c++ program but now I need to store on the hard disk permanently some settings about the program.

Where do I have to store this data ?

> - In a sqlite database ?
> - In the windows registry ( if linux ? ) ?
> - In a XML file
> - In other files ?

Comment: It depends on what kind of data it is and on how you will be using it in the future. Without such information this question is too generic to answer. If it's just "some settings", then a simple .ini file next to your binary should be quite sufficient.

Comment: @Jon: that sounds like a bad idea on pretty much any system today. On Linux, you'd need to be root; on Windows you'd run into UAC, and on embedded systems the binary might very well be in ROM.

Comment: @MSalters: That's not true, because the program will be stored into the user's home directory.

Comment: @Jon: can you write the requirements for xRobot, overriding the guidelines from the respective OS vendors? @nightcracker: please note that I responded to Jon's suggestion, not xRobot's valid question. Jon came up with the generally rejected idea of storing an INI file next to (in the directory of) the executable. In _that_ case, my statement is entirely true. Not ranting, Microsoft has been quite vocal on this point.

Comment: @MSalters: Wow. For one, my previous comment was "irony with a moral", both parts of which were evidently lost. Also, the guidelines from the Windows vendor say to just put anything your program wants in `AppData`, in which case there would be no UAC trouble to begin with. Are you trying to make a point?

Comment: @Jon: yes. My point is that you should follow Microsoft's guidance (use `Appdata` for data), not yours (next to the binary, i.e. ` \Program Files\ `)

Comment: @MSalters: Did it occur to you that the binary *might not be* in `Program Files`? Given that the OP gives no information about what type of program it is, if it's distributed as a binary, if it has an installer, etc etc? That was the point *I* am trying to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type and size of data. For small and less complex data simple text files are better. for complex data you can use XML or sqlite database. If you need to write complex queries go for sqlite. It stores data in files but will give better query options.

Comment: Did I mention how much I detest XML? Oh please, avoid it for purposes other than DOM. Oh please, I beg! Help making this world a better place for our children.

Comment: U did not. Now you have and the way you are begging. I will be careful :)

Answer (score 4):

It completely depends how much information it is and for which platform.

Viable options are a .ini file http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Accessing_INI_files and for more data a SQLite database. I'm not a big fan of XML files.

Answer (score 0):

Modern applications use the system registry to store configuration information.

See the windows article: Using the Registry in a C++ Application

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838625.aspx

Comment: No, they don't. Registry is used at most for installation information.